# How to use headless chrome with capybara and selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara, google-chrome-headless

Chrome version: 59.0.3071.104

Using Cucumber, Capybara, Selenium to implement automation testing with Headless Chrome.

> features/support/env.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara/cucumber'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, args: ['headless'])
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

When running a cucumber test, it says:

> WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :args or :switches is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options#add_argument instead.

What is the correct way to use capybara and selenium with Headless Chrome. Thank you.

EDIT 1: I tried the following using [Ruby-Binding](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings), [Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) and [Working Example](http://blog.faraday.io/headless-chromium/). But it gives errors as well.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app, 
    browser: :chrome, 
    desired_capabilities: driver
  )
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

Error:

```
> undefined method `each' for
> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities:0xd13baac> (NoMethodError)
```

Edit 2:
Download the latest [ChromeDriver 2.30](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Using the example from [ChromeDriver Capabilities](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) & [Chrome Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) I get an error.

> Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    "chromeOptions" => {
      "binary" => "/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe",
      "args" => [ "--disable-web-security", "--headless" ]
    }
  )  
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app, 
    browser: :chrome, 
    desired_capabilities: caps
  )
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) Make sure you don't have another registered driver, I made this mistake myself and had an `iphone` driver, which was using the `args` in the old way, that's why I was getting the warning.

2) Make sure you have Chrome version **57+** on Linux, **59+** on macOS or **60+** on Windows;

3) Add/update the gem `selenium-webdriver`;

4) Add the following **driver** to your `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb`:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome,
    options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: %w[headless disable-gpu])
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

Comment: I used the same but getting Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError:
  invalid argument (Session info: headless chrome=93.0.4577.63)

Answer (score 10):

## Update 2020-02-01

Support for ChromeDriver ended on [Mar 24, 2019](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper/issues/83), creator recommended everybody to move to https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers, having said that, the following is a configuration that worked for me:

```rb
require "test_helper"

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driver = ENV['DRIVER'] ? ENV['DRIVER'].to_sym : :headless_chrome
  driven_by :selenium, using: driver, screen_size: [1400, 1400]
end
```

When running your tests, you can also specify a different driver by passing the `DRIVER` variable like:

```sh
$ DRIVER=firefox bin/rails test:system
$ DRIVER=headless_firefox bin/rails test:system
$ DRIVER=chrome bin/rails test:system
$ DRIVER=headless_chrome bin/rails test:system
```

---

### Previous Answer

The simplest way to run headless Chrome with Rails apps is to add the following gems to the `Gemfile`

```
gem 'chromedriver-helper'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

And update your `application_system_test_case.rb` with the following:

```
require "test_helper"

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driver = ENV['CHROME_HEADLESS'] == 'false' ? :selenium_chrome : :selenium_chrome_headless
  driven_by driver, screen_size: [1400, 1400]
end
```

There is no need to pass `args` as the drivers are already available to use, available drivers are `:rack_test`, `:selenium`, `:selenium_chrome`, `:selenium_chrome_headless`.

You can run `Headless Chrome`

```
$ bin/rails test:system
```

Or you can also run `Chrome` and see test running on it

```
$ CHROME_HEADLESS=false bin/rails test:system
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows support is coming in Chrome 60.

Download "Chome Canary" and give the installation path as a `binary` in `chromeOptions.`

Download the latest "chromedriver" and add to path in Environment Variables.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    "chromeOptions" => {
      "binary" => "C:/Users/YOURUSERNAME/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome SxS/Application/chrome.exe",
      "args" => [ "--disable-web-security", "--headless", "--disable-gpu" ]
    }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app, 
    browser: :chrome, 
    desired_capabilities: caps
  )
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get this working with the current version of Chrome, but it would display a blank window. If you want to get rid of that, then you need to use the "Chrome Canary" build.

The code below is a combination of the answers that @lucas-caton and @shawn-derik, but solves the issue I mentioned above.

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
      binary: 'C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome SxS/Application/chrome.exe',
      args: %w[no-sandbox headless disable-gpu]
    )
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## March 2024 update:

1. Run `sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver` in the underlying OS.
2. Put the following contents into corresponding files:

test helper:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a surprisingly hard time getting my rspec + capybara + chrome (headful) system specs to run with chrome headless.

#### What worked for me

Add this to the very end of `spec/rails_helper.rb` (not inside any other block/code, just at the very end of the file on its own).

```rb
# spec/rails_helper.rb

if ENV['HEADLESS'] == "true"
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.before(:each, type: :system) do
      driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can do

```bash
# run specs in chrome headless
HEADLESS=true bundle exec rspec

# run specs in chrome normally (headful)
bundle exec rspec
```

#### Note

Note that if you don't care about having the option and just want headless all the time, just plonk this at the end of `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end
end
```