# Getting Headless Chrome to work with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

Im a bit stuck, im following thoughtbots tutorial on this and everything "looks" correct: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/headless-feature-specs-with-chrome

- I've verified my Chrome is version 59
- I've used brew to install chromedriver, and verified it's version 2.3 at least

my `rails_helper` file (the relevant part) looks like this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    'chromeOptions:' => { args: %w(headless disable-gpu) }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

Using the `chromedriver-helper` gem does allow me to use chrome just fine, but it doesn't stay headless. Also when I would check it I would confirm on the chrome that the automation test uses that no `--headless` flag appears.

What it's giving me now using the `brew install chromedriver` is:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
       unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515
```

So something seems off....it doesn't seem to know how to connect the brew chromedriver version..however most tutorials don't seem to say anything about linking anything using the brew version.

Any ideas? (Im Running on Rails 4.1 btw)

Comment: I would look into using poltergeist with phantomjs and capybara.  It is fully headless & handles js great.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Thats what I used before, however I wanted to at least give headless chrome a try.

Comment: do `bundle exec chromedriver -v` and tell us what it prints, also - comment out the :chrome driver registration so you only have :headless_chrome - that will make sure you're not setting the driver to :chrome somewhere else

Comment: @bkunzi01 Unfortunately, phantomjs currently has the downside of not supporting anything beyond ES5 or newer CSS (grids, etc)- which means a lot of newer stuff requires polyfilling and transpiling every piece of JS in the app -  headless chrome makes things a lot cleaner from a testing perspective

Comment: @ThomasWalpole `bundler: failed to load command: chromedriver (/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/chromedriver)
Gem::LoadError: chromedriver-helper is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.`  I don't have chromedriver helper, as im using `brew install chromedriver` to run it. 

I am running this under dev, for the database were using, but that shouldn't be relevant

Also I get the same issue when commenting out the other portion.

Comment: You need to completely remove chromedriver-helper and all of its remnants from your machine (including deleting /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/chromedriver).  Can you actually just run `chromedriver -v` without the bundle exec.

Comment: ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262)  is what that returns, I did remove chromedriver from my $HOME/.chromedriver directory

Comment: I do see chromedriver and chromedriver-update in the directory you mentioned however

Comment: Yeah - remove them from that /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin directory -- unfortunately the chromedriver-helper gem leaves them behind and they still get added to the path by bundler when your tests run, which means they get preference over the instance installed by brew

Comment: This guy got it working with `'chromeOptions' => ` instead of `'chromeOptions:' =>`. Note the missing colon

https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper/issues/42#issuecomment-309245224

Comment: @ThomasWalpole do I remove both chromedriver and chromedriver-update  from that directory?

Comment: @msmith1114 Yes - if you no longer have chromedriver-helper in your gemfile remove both

Comment: Hmmmm no luck, I also tried what @Nultyi suggested as well. Same error unfortunately: `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
       unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515`

Comment: @msmith1114 Try the `bundle exec chromedriver -v`   when that correctly tells you 2.30  your setup should then be correct

Comment: @Nultyi . Good catch -- it should be   `chromeOptions: { args: %w(headless disable-gpu) }` IIRC, although that wouldn't have any effect on chromedriver not starting

Comment: I've got it working on Ubuntu, downloaded the binary here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html, extracted and added it to my users path ~/bin. Capybara picked it up no problem.

Have you run `find / -name 'chromedriver*'` to see if theres anything else left on your machine that could be confusing matters?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I get: `
rbenv: chromedriver: command not found

The `chromedriver' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.0.0-p598`

So I guess I need to delete that one too in rbenv?

Removing that just leaves a `rbenv: chromedriver: command not found` afterwards.

Comment: Try run `chromedriver` in your terminal. and visit http://127.0.0.1:9515 in any browser. You should get a white window with `unknown command:`

Comment: I get `rbenv: chromedriver: command not found` which is weird cause it's def. brew installed

Comment: you can run `bundle exec which chromedriver` to try and figure out what stub it's actually running - and then remove that

Comment: `/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/chromedriver` is what I see, isn't that where brew installs it though?

Comment: you should delete the chromedriver references in rbenv shims directory. likely thats whats giving you the `rbenv: chromedriver: command not found` error. They'll be higher in your PATH probably than the brew executable

Comment: Whew! that worked! thanks. Wonder what installed it there?

Comment: that would have been the `chromedriver-helper`

Comment: Your chromedriver should be version `>= 2.30` not `>= 2.3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use headless chrome with capybara and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591612/how-to-use-headless-chrome-with-capybara-and-selenium)

Comment: I guess someone can put an answer so I can upvote it and accept since my question was indeed answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using `brew` to install chromedriver you need to completely remove `chromedriver-helper` and all the binaries and stubs it has installed.  This is because `bundler` adds the installed binaries/stubs into the path before the version of chromedriver installed by brew and therefore shadows it.  You can use

```
bundle exec which chromedriver
```

to find out which chromedriver is actually being used when you run your tests.  If it's not the one installed by `brew` (usually /usr/local/bin/chromedriver) then keep removing them until it is.